# Using variables as 'key' in a python get from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, get, key

I'm using yFinance with Python and I have a list of ticker symbols in a csv file that I wish to research.  I read the cvs into Python, create a dictionary using:

```
ticker_dict = {t: yf.Ticker(t) for t in ticker_list}
```

As a trial, I want to grab the ticker name using:

`print(ticker_dict[tmp].info.get('longName'))` where tmp is a variable pulled from the list.

My problem, I think, is the tmp is being perceived as the key instead the value tmp represents.  I can hardcode the expression

`print(ticker_dict['VTHRX'].info.get('longName'))` and get a result.

is there a way to use a variable in the above expression to get the same result?

Comment: I dont see any issue here. You can use tmp variable as key here. Check what is value of tmp you are getting.

Comment: If you're reading `tmp` from a file, make sure you strip off newlines.

Comment: I was thinking that too.  thanks for confirming.  So, the solution must be something simple I'm overlooking.  The key in the dictionary appears as VTHRX when I print key, but the expression only works in the expression when I use double quotes.  What am I overlooking?